# SQL Server / Hierarchy ID Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

Take the following scenario...

```
CREATE TABLE #ParentItems (
ItemID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
HID HIERARCHYID,
TreeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
HIDLevel AS HID.GetLevel()
)

CREATE TABLE #ChildItems (
ItemID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
HID HIERARCHYID,
TreeID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
HIDLevel AS HID.GetLevel()
)   

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX PInd ON #ParentItems(TreeID, HIDLevel, HID)
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CInd ON #ChildItems(TreeID, HIDLevel, HID)
```

So two tables, the parent table has a bunch of IDs/HIDs which I know are ancestors of items in the child tables. There are multiple different tree structures in each, hence the TreeId (all HIDs for the same tree, share the same treeID).

Assume #ParentItems and #ChildItems have 20,000+ rows in each.

The following query is reasonable fast (for what it's doing...) it takes around a second to complete.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LIParent.ItemID as ParentID
              , LIChild.ItemID as ChildID 
FROM #ParentItems LIParent INNER JOIN #ChildItems LIChild 
ON LIChild.HID.IsDescendantOf(LIParent.HID)=1
```

However, this ignores the TreeID relationship as well. Now the second I add "WHERE LIParent.TreeID = LIChild.TreeID" to the query (or add it to the join) the whole query jumps up to around 30 second execution time.
This seems like a very simple change, and I believe the index is in place... but it slows down massively.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: ADD the where condition in your join statement so that most of the work is done before it self.if you want try and see this once and see if it works.

Comment: hi developer, it doesn't make any difference whether the check is in the join, or in the where clause.  identical performance (and execution plan).

Comment: Then Try out for Referential Integrity between two tables. create foreign key relationship or composite key relationship. It adds more performance on the indexing.

Comment: Hi developer, unfortunately you cannot use FK constraints between temporary tables.